# can't run the function within Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

trying to run the main function within the Jupyter notebook. the error states that a function for loading image is not defined. But I implemented it above already. what is the problem? was the path of image file set wrong?

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpdYQ.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MERD8.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWTkD.png
```

Comment: Posting images of code is frowned upon. You can write three back ticks, hit return, paste your code, then hit return again and close the code block using three more back tick characters (`). I think there is also a button you can press that lets you post code blocks.

Comment: Have you tried changing the name of your function and calling it again with the new name? I know that sounds odd, but it was a trick that get me past what seemed to be similar weirdness the other day.

Comment: Hi Wayne, thx for the reply. I just rerun the whole thing the other day and just worked, it's weird

Comment: I'd agree it was weird, but like I said, a similar thing happened to me recently. Even a kernel restart didn't seem to fix it. Glad you got past it though.